# Is there is way to get back jenkins deleted workspace folder?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I was running some jenkins test jobs for my local app, but by mistake, I deleted the local workspace folder. Is there a way to get the deleted workspace folder back?

My workspace contains some important files.
Thanks in advance.

i tried multiple ways but could not found the solution.